# Unpack a function into a data frame

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a function which returns two list, so a can save those in two variables like:

```
list_a,list_b = my_function(input)
```

I want to save this directly into a dataframe, something like this:

```
df[['list_a','list_b']]  =  my_function(input)
```

I got the following error:

```
array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
df['B'], df['C'] = my_function()
```

to unpack the tuple of lists returned by `my_function` and assign the lists to `df['B']` and `df['C']`:

```
import pandas as pd
N = 5
def my_function():
    return [10]*N, [20]*N

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1]*N})
df['B'], df['C'] = my_function()
```

yields

```
   A   B   C
0  1  10  20
1  1  10  20
2  1  10  20
3  1  10  20
4  1  10  20
```

Note that the lengths of the lists returned by `my_function` must match the length of `df`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

list_a, list_b = my_function(input)
df = pd.DataFrame([list_a, list_b], columns=['a','b'])
```

or combined in to one line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_function(input)), columns=['a','b'])
```